# Is Greater Link Spell as limitless as it appears?

Tags: spells, metamagic, dnd-3e

I recently found [this link](https://www.wowarchives.us/magic-mayhem/greater-link-spell-%5Bmetamagic.html), allegedly giving the text for two metamagic feats from Magic and Mayhem. The following, with typos corrected, got my attention:

> Greater Link Spell [Metamagic]
> You can cast any number of spells at the same time.
> Prerequisite: Link Spell.
> Benefit: As Link Spell, except that you may link any number of spells together.

> Link Spell [Metamagic]
> You can cast two spells at the same time.
> Benefit: When preparing spells, you can link two spells together. These spells must then be cast at the same time; when you cast one, you automatically cast the other. The casting time is equal to the longest casting time listed between the two spells. (For example, if one spell has a casting time of "1 standard action" and the other has a casting time of "1 round," you need a full-round action to cast them both.) You choose all targets normally for the spells; they can have different targets or the same targets.
> Each linked spell takes up a spell slot one level higher than normal.

Assuming that this is the correct text, is Greater Link Spell really as limitless as it appears? As I read it, I could have 100 fifth-level spells with a casting time of 1 round or less, prepare them all as a single Greater Link Spell with a casting time of 1 round, and this would take up one sixth-level spell slot **with absolutely no other costs**. Is this correct? I fear any Wizard that can cast Fireball 1000 times per round.

Comment: Every time I think I've seen the pinnacle on how broken 3e can be, I find a question like this which raises it to another level.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I didn't even try. There's probably worse stuff just on that one link.

Comment: RE: "These spells must then be cast at the same time; when you cast one, you automatically cast the other." Even if such casting is automatic, a caster can't cast a *fireball* spell that's not prepared. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It looks to me like you're adding the metamagic during preparation, meaning that in one slot you've got two spelled linked together, i.e. Linked Fireball Fireball.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not seeing anything about the caster being able to prepare two spells in the same slot. What am I missing?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It depends on how you read "_Each linked spell takes up a spell slot one level higher than normal._". Either a single slot takes up (for example) Linked Fireball True Seeing, which is therefore a linked spell, or Linked Fireball is in one slot and Linked True Seeing is in another, and they're both linked spells.

Comment: @J.Mini That seems to leave unknowable the ultimate spell slot. That is, a wizard prepares *fireball* and *acid splash* in the same slot. How does the wizard determine the level of that linked spell slot? Does the linked spell occupy the higher 5th-level slot or the lower 2nd-level slot? And how does the reader know?

Comment: @HeyICanChan the correct answer is "both". The *fireball* spell occupies a 5th-level slot and *acid splash* occupies a 2nd-level slot. Nothing about this metamagic feat says that "both spells occupy the same slot", ergo each spell occupies its own slot, they're just both cast together. Similarly, if someone attempted to dispel or counter the casting, each spell would have to be dispelled/countered individually; dispelling/countering one will cause that one to fizzle but the other will still go off. They are *linked*, not *merged*.

Comment: @DoktorJ (That actually articulates my understanding of the feat. I was trying to understand how the asker was reading it differently. Sincerely, though, thank you for the patient explanation, and consider making that an answer; such details might be of use to other readers.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan [sure, why not](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174977/is-greater-link-spell-as-limitless-as-it-appears/175463#175463)? XD

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No.**

> Link Spell [Metamagic]
>
> You can cast two spells at the same time.
>
> Benefit: When preparing spells, you can link two spells together. These spells
> must then be cast at the same time; when you cast one, you automatically cast
> the other. The casting time is equal to the longest casting time listed between
> the two spells. (For example, if one spell has a casting time of "1 standard
> action" and the other has a casting time of "1 round," you need a full-round
> action to cast them both.) You choose all targets normally for the spells; they
> can have different targets or the same targets.
>
> **Each linked spell takes up a spell slot one level higher than normal.**
> (Emphasis mine)

This means that to prepare 1000 linked fireballs, a Wizard needs 1000 4th level spell slots.

Comment: How did you reach this conclusion? Dumb it down for me. I really can't see your logic. You only have one linked spell - Greater Linked Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball Fireball...

Comment: @J.Mini Spells linked by the Link Spell feat cost two spell slots, each 1 level higher than normal. Greater Link Spell removes the cap on the number of linked spells, but does nothing to remove the need for a spell slot per linked spell.

Comment: _Spells linked by the Link Spell feat **cost two spell slots**_ - Source?

Comment: @J.Mini See the highlighted part of the quote in my answer

Comment: So your argument is that this metamagic applies to each spells that it's linking? So when you want to link two spells, say Fireball and True Seeing, you're actually preparing Linked Fireball and Linked True Seeing? But Linked Fireball is a 4th level spell and Linked True Seeing is 7th level?

Comment: @J.Mini Yes, that is how I interpret that sentence.

Comment: @J.Mini I think the disconnect is that you're reading it as "all of the linked spells become one spell", but neither of the feats say that that occurs, they only says that you cast all of them at the same time.

Comment: Note that this feat is still stupidly good. There are lots of ways to reduce the cost of a metamagic feat by 1, and at that point you can cast a 20d4 cone of flame for 4 1st level slots, or a 20d6 fireball with 2 3rd. The spells break the action economy, which is practically the only thing limiting full casters anyhow.  Sure, its the same number of spell slots, but fights should never last more than one round again. That's why these feats are nearly universally banned and treated on about the same level as *Wish* abuse and Manipulate Form.

Comment: If the intention was that the whole shebang is just one spell, there would be no need for the word "each." They would write "the" instead. And then you would have to figure out what is "normal" for this weird linked spell thingy, so that you can add one to whatever that number ends up being. This is obviously untenable.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you must create the Linked Spell 'chain' during preparations (if applicable) so you would be limiting yourself to casting *all* of the spells at once, expending all the spell slots, when it could be overkill if not prepared exactingly

Comment: But yes, the ability to break action economy makes this a *startlingly* broken ability

Comment: @Ifusaso If you link 3 3rd-level fireballs sure you have a single attack that does stupid amounts of damage, but then what do you do if you're facing an unexpected fire giant? Whoops, your link is utterly useless. What if you're under siege and attackers come in waves? You blow everything on the first wave and then have nothing left for subsequent waves. The link trades flexibility and versatility for raw power. Is it overpowered? Sure. But I wouldn't call it "startlingly broken". A good GM can tweak their campaign to limit greater link's usefulness if a player leans on it too much.

Comment: I feel like you misunderstand me. I started by pointing out a significant weakness of the metamagic, not hailing it. However, if, as they should be, the Wizard is appropriately prepared it defies almost any other scale of power. Being able to cast as many spells as you like in one turn, even with the glaring flaws, overcomes the single greatest limiter in combat rounds. Measuring it solely on that one facet, it is far and beyond more powerful than other feat options. Perhaps broken isn't the appropriate word (I think it is), but overpowererd doesn't come close.

Answer (score 2):

I think a greater understanding of this metamagic feat might be reached by framing the question differently. As asked in the comments by [Hey I Can Chan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8610/hey-i-can-chan),

> [If] a wizard prepares fireball and acid splash, how does the wizard determine the level of that linked spell slot? Does the linked spell occupy the higher 5th-level slot or the lower 2nd-level slot? And how does the reader know?

### The correct answer is "both". They are *linked*, not *merged*.

The fireball spell (a 4th level spell) occupies a 5th-level slot and acid splash (a 1st level spell) occupies a 2nd-level slot. Nothing about this metamagic feat says that "both spells occupy the same slot", ergo each spell occupies its own slot, they're just both cast together. To cast 1,000 linked fireballs, the caster would need a thousand 5th level spell slots.

Similarly, if someone attempted to dispel or counter the casting, each spell would have to be dispelled/countered individually; dispelling/countering one will cause that one to fizzle but the other will still go off.